# Android studio: Phone call state

Tags: android

I want to set the phone state to ringing when I press a button. Is there any way I could set the phone state to ringing without actually receiving a phone call?
I have glanced this [site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager) but didn't find any setter methods for the phone call state.
Is it possible to fool android system that it is ringing without actually receiving any call using **VoIP**?

Comment: you need it and real device or emulator ?

Comment: @ismail alaoui i need it in a real device.

Comment: It's eserved as 'system only'. but you can do it on emulator

Comment: no. because phone state changed listener call when you receive call on your phone ,

Comment: IMO You cannot change the phone call state. The phone call UI you see is actually from the built-in Phone app. You can build the same UI and try to trigger it by service or timer

Comment: is it possible to change the state by using VoIP?